# How do I combine aggregate_rollover and linked charts?

Tags: javascript, metricsgraphicsjs

How do I combine functionality of both `aggregate_rollover` and `linked` charts?

Both of these work for me when used without the other (individually) but when used together only `aggregate_rollover` is in effect.

Does anyone know if this should work or if it's a bug? I'm using v2.9.

I've tried systematically commenting lines out to see of anything is interfering with the linking but no joy.

```
var opts = {
  data: (linedata.length > 0 ? linedata : undefined),
  height: ($scope.config.size === 12 ? 400 : 200),
  target: '#' + $scope.mgLineId,
  x_accessor: 't',
  y_accessor: 'v', //Link all the charts
  aggregate_rollover: true,
  linked : true,
  linked_format : '%Y-%m-%d-%H'
};
etc graphData = MG.data_graphic(opts)
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of what you're working with so maybe we can see what's wrong?

Comment: Hi Jeff, Thanks for helping :) Here's the code for the graph options etc (wel, gist of it). I've inherited this and so can't vouch for its sanity though 've tried systematically commenting lines out to see of anything is interfering with the linking but no joy: 

`var opts = {
  data: (linedata.length > 0 ? linedata : undefined),
  height: ($scope.config.size === 12 ? 400 : 200),
  target: '#' + $scope.mgLineId,
  x_accessor: 't',
  y_accessor: 'v',
  //Link all the charts
  aggregate_rollover: true,
  linked : true,
  linked_format : '%Y-%m-%d-%H'
};

etc

graphData = MG.data_graphic(opts);`